# Завершение работы корутины

Tags: python

Имею дополнительный поток, в котором создаётся корутина. По - сути как корутина она не используется, мне надо просто прервать её выполнение. Я набросал следующий код:

```
class TestThread(Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        self.task = self.loop.create_task(self.printNumbers())

    async def printNumbers(self):
        try:
            for i in range(0, 1000000):
                print(i)
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            raise
    
    def run(self):
        self.loop.run_forever()

    def stop(self):
        self.task.cancel()
        self.loop.stop()

def main():
    testThread = TestThread()
    testThread.start()
    time.sleep(5)
    testThread.stop()
```

Однако работа корутины не останавливается. Какие есть варианты?

Answer (score 0):

Вижу Вы хотите остановить поток. Насколько мне известно поток нельзя остановить до его завершения, до завершения цикла. Но можно им управлять. Например ввести логическую переменную остановки цикла изменяемую вне потока. Тогда выполнение потока остановится.

Comment: Дело в том, что в потоке очень длинный код, и не хотелось расставлять везде проверки на конец (флаг и тд). Думал есть способ красивее.

Comment: Боюсь, что способа красивее нет, красивее изучить управление потаками и писать функции  под красивое возможно даже стандартное управление потоками.